# Vaadin field binding nested bean from superclass

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, vaadin

I have a problem with binding inherited attributes from the mother class.
I have an entity`Person` and `Staff` where the class `staff` extends `person`:

```
public abstract class Person {
      private String firstName;
      private String lastName;
      private String phone;
      //... getters and setters ... //
}
```

and

```
public class Staff extends Person {
      private String identificationCode;
      private UnavailabilityReason reason;
      private Address address;
      //... getters and setters ... //
}
```

I have a form for editing Staff where I succeed to bind `identificationCode, reason and address` but not with `firstName, lastName and phone`

Can someone help me?

Comment: Please provide the form code and the code responsible for binding. I think it should be possible without problems.